# C-x and M-x remapped to SPC and SPC-SPC

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs, evil

What would be the best way to configure Emacs to handle the above keybindings for vanilla Emacs? Specifically, I'd like to have `SPC` work as `C-x` and `SPC SPC` work as `M-x`.   I love Spacemacs for the bindings, but want to build up a vanilla install with a better understanding of the underpinnings.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "SPC") ctl-x-map)
(define-key ctl-x-map (kbd "SPC") 'execute-extended-command)
```

Although occasionally modes will define a `SPC` binding which would take precedence, so rather than using the global map you're perhaps wanting a solution like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683425/globally-override-key-binding-in-emacs

I don't really understand how you're planning to type spaces without a great deal of muscle-memory issues, unless you make the new behaviour modal -- but you've not described any requirement for that.